# OneNote 16.27 for iPhone won't attach pages as pdfs to Outlook 3.34.0 and gives no warning

Tags: ios, email, pdf, ms-office

I just sent an email out to a bunch of people with a procedure attached to it, and when I sent the email it was attached. When the people (and myself) received the email, it wasn't there!

Is this a bug?  The attachment was a pdf file.  It's making me look like an idiot.  Thanks Microshaft!

Comment: How did you attach the note to the email?  I can send attachments from OneNote 16.27 on iOS with my MS Outlook iOS app without a problem.  It's not a bug.

Comment: I was in OneNote, clicked the hamburger button at the top of a page on my phone ‘...’ and selected ‘Send Copy of Page’; it then opened in the Outlook app and it was attached to the email as a pdf.  I sent it and poof no attachment.

Comment: Are you sure the server you sent the email through didn't strip the attachment?

Comment: @MarcWilson How would I tell if it did?  It’s just a pdf.

Comment: log into your account via webmail and look at the sent folder and the email message in question and see if the attachment is there, if it is then something else stripped the attachment downstream from your email server

Comment: @SteveChambers okay I logged into the OWA and there is no attachment on an email I sent with the OneNote page attached.

Comment: Have you tried this again to different recipients, perhaps sending to yourself?

Comment: Yes, in fact the email I checked was just that; the colleague I sent it too doesn’t have the attachment.

Comment: OK a couple of things to try, attach it agin to an Outlook email but don't SEND it. Look in drafts and see if the attachment is there. Also try it with mail.app if you can. I tried on my iPhone and it worked a treat so it's not an interaction bug with OneNote and Outlook. Also, turn the phone off and then back on again.